# How to convert initials in one array to match a value in a second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
array1 = ['bob', 's', 'paul'];
array2 = ['bob', 'sue', 'paul'];
```

where I want to convert the initial in array1: 's' to the corresponding name in array2: 'sue'.

I also want this to work in the inverse, where:

```
array1 = ['bob', 'sue', 'paul'];
array2 = ['bob', 's', 'paul'];
```

so that 'sue' in array1 would convert to 's' matching array2.

so far, I have this function:

```
function findName(arr1, arr2) {
        for (let initial of arr1) {
            if (initial.length === 1) {
                return arr2.findIndex(name => name[0] === initial) != -1
            }
        }
    }
```

which will return true if an initial finds a matching name, but I need the function to actually create array3 such that it will convert the initial.

In other words:

```
array1 = ['bob', 's', 'paul'];
array2 = ['bob', 'sue', 'paul'];
// array3 = ['bob', 'sue', 'paul']; //array 3 maintains the same sequence order as array 1

array1 = ['b', 'sue', 'paul'];
array2 = ['s', 'paul', 'bob'];
// array3 = ['bob', 's', 'paul']; //array 3 maintains the same sequence order as array 1

array1 = ['b', 'sue', 'paul', 'robert'];
array2 = ['s', 'paul', 'bob'];
// array3 = ['bob', 's', 'paul', 'robert']; //array 3 maintains the same sequence order as array 1

array1 = ['b', 'sue', 'paul'];
array2 = ['s', 'paul', 'bob', 'robert'];
// array3 = ['bob', 's', 'paul']; //array 3 maintains the same sequence order as array 1
```

In cases where more than one of the same initial exists, just convert the first initial and retain the second:

```
array1 = ['b', 'b', 'sue', 'paul'];
array2 = ['s', 'paul', 'bob', 'robert'];
// array3 = ['bob', 'b', 's', 'paul']; //array 3 maintains the same sequence order as array 1
```

unless the initials find a matching set, convert them sequentially:

```
array1 = ['b', 'b', 'sue', 'paul'];
array2 = ['s', 'paul', 'bob', 'robert', 'bill'];
// array3 = ['bob', 'bill', 's', 'paul']; //array 3 maintains the same sequence order as array 1
```

I need to be able to use array3 outside this function.

Comment: Use `return arr1.map(…)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert initials in one array to match a value in a second array

```js
let array1 = ['b', 'b', 'sue', 'paul'];
let array2 = ['s', 'paul', 'bob', 'robert', 'bill'];
let array3 = [];
array1.forEach(function(element) {
  let item =array2.find((el) => el.startsWith(element[0]));
  array3.push(item);
  var index = array2.indexOf(item);
  if (index > -1) {
    array2.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
 console.log(array3);
```

Comment: You should probably avoid the duplicate `array2.find((el) => el.startsWith(element[0]))` call

Answer (score 0):

You're already using `findIndex` to locate where in the array the element is; so instead of throwing that away and only returning a boolean to tell if it was -1 or not, use it to index the array (if, of course, it isn't -1).

```
i = arr2.findIndex(...);
result = (i > -1)? arr2[i] : initial;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` over the first array and use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) like this:

```js
function getArray3(array1, array2) {
  let array3 = array1.map(a => {
      let found;
      if (a.length === 1) {
        found = array2.findIndex(b => b.startsWith(a))
      } else {
        found = array2.findIndex(b => b.length === 1 && a.startsWith(b))
      }

      return found === -1 ? a : array2.splice(found, 1)[0]
    })

  return array3
}

console.log(getArray3(['bob', 's', 'paul'], ['bob', 'sue', 'paul']))
// ['bob', 'sue', 'paul']; 

console.log(getArray3(['b', 'sue', 'paul'], ['s', 'paul', 'bob']))
// ['bob', 's', 'paul']; //array 3 maintains the same sequence order as array 1

console.log(getArray3(['b', 'sue', 'paul', 'robert'], ['s', 'paul', 'bob']))
// ['bob', 's', 'paul', 'robert']

console.log(getArray3(['b', 'b', 'sue', 'paul'], ['s', 'paul', 'bob', 'robert']))
// ['bob', 'b', 's', 'paul']

console.log(getArray3(['b', 'b', 'sue', 'paul'], ['s', 'paul', 'bob', 'robert', 'bill']))
// ['bob', 'bill', 's', 'paul']
```

You could take a clone of the `array2` using `[...array2]` if you don't want to mutate `array2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and find

**Here idea is -**

- First we loop through `A` parameter.
- For each value of `A` we match it with initials in parameter `B`. alreadyUsed is an object to keep track of previously used substutions.
- If we find a value which not falsy as well as not used for any of previous substitution.than we map it to final output. if not than we keep value unchanged

```js
let switcher = (A,B)=>{
  let alreadyUsed = {}
  return A.map(e => {
    let value = B.find(b => b.startsWith( e[0] ) && !alreadyUsed[b] ) || e
    if(value && !alreadyUsed[value] ){
      alreadyUsed[value] = true
    }
    return value
  })
}


let array1 = ['bob', 's', 'paul'];
let array2 = ['bob', 'sue', 'paul'];

console.log(switcher(array1,array2))

let a1 = ['b', 'b', 'sue', 'paul'];
let a2 = ['s', 'paul', 'bob', 'robert', 'bill'];
console.log(switcher(a1,a2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution combining [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
const mapInitials = (a1, a2) => {
  a2 = [...a2]; // clone because we're going to be modifying this one
  return a1.map((s1) => {
    const i = a2.findIndex(s2 => s2[0] === s1[0]);
    return i < 0 ? s1 : a2.splice(i, 1)[0];
  })
};

const test = (a1, a2) => console.log(...mapInitials(a1, a2));

test(['bob', 's', 'paul'],
     ['bob', 'sue', 'paul']);
  // ['bob', 'sue', 'paul']

test(['b', 'sue', 'paul'],
     ['s', 'paul', 'bob']);
  // ['bob', 's', 'paul']

test(['b', 'sue', 'paul', 'robert'],
     ['s', 'paul', 'bob']);
  // ['bob', 's', 'paul', 'robert']

test(['b', 'sue', 'paul'],
     ['s', 'paul', 'bob', 'robert']);
  // ['bob', 's', 'paul']

test(['b', 'b', 'sue', 'paul'],
     ['s', 'paul', 'bob', 'robert']);
  // ['bob', 'b', 's', 'paul']

test(['b', 'b', 'sue', 'paul'],
     ['s', 'paul', 'bob', 'robert', 'bill']);
  // ['bob', 'bill', 's', 'paul']
```